# Formatting currency for AED

Tags: asp.net, localization, currency

I'm currently doing a project for a client in Dubai, where the currency is AED. Throughout the project I used {0:c} assuming that setting the local in web-config would sort me out.

I set the [culture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) in web.config using:

```
<globalization culture="ar-AE" />
```

This used arabic symbols for the currency, which I assumed the client would want (turns out I assumed a bit too much). They actually wanted the currency to look like:

```
AED 50.00
```

I'm not sure if this is the standard format or not. Is there a way in web.config to make it use this format. I ended up hard coding all the currencies, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the current culture/region is set, this is avilable in the following:

<del>string symbol = System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol;</del>

```
string symbol = System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol;
```

Comment: The culture region is set, but I get an arabic symbol for the currency, when the client wants it to say AED 50.00. I don't know enough about AED to say what the standard should be.

Comment: @Richard Sorry, I meant `.ISOCurrencySymbol` should get the 3 letters "AED".

Comment: That's ace. Is there a way to tell it to use the ISOCurrencySymbol format for all currencies in web.config so I can continue to use just {0:c} in things like bound columns.

Comment: @Richard Yes I'd be interested to know if you could do that (I had a quick look myself and I couldn't see how). I think you can write your own custom format provider to do it, but not too sure.